# Remove duplicate lines repeating immediately ignoring the first field

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I try to move from (stars are just here to indicate which lines I'm keeping)

```
*2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:20:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:30:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
*2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:50:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
*2020-12-15 20:00:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```

to

```
2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 20:00:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```

I want to remove the duplicate lines from a group of identical lines without taking into account the date but I don't know how to go about it.
I tried sorting from the second argument but it doesn't take into account the "group" of lines

```
cat <my file> | sort -t";" -k2 -u
```

Give me that

```
2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the **-m** flag, `sort` assumes the input is already sorted and doesn't sort it again; which is exactly what you're looking for here.

```
$ sort -m -t';' -k2 -u <file
2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 20:00:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not really sorting. You are attempting to print a row if it is different from previous one, ignoring date-time column. You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ';' '{s=$0; sub(/^[^;]+;/, "", s)} p != s; {p=s}' file

2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 20:00:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```

Answer (score 3):

Just tell `uniq` to skip the date field:

```
$ uniq -s 20 file
2020-12-15 19:10:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 19:40:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);100.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
2020-12-15 20:00:00;34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm
```